# Cohomology of varieties defined solely by their embedding equation

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

In textbooks where sheaf cohomology is introduced, example computations are typically carried out on known spaces, e.g. $\mathbb{P}^n$.

However, suppose we are handed a description of a variety solely by its defining equation, e.g.,

$$v^2w + w^2x + x^2y + y^2z + z^2v = 0$$

where $x,y,z,w,v$ are homogeneous coordinates on $\mathbb{P}^4$. How does one then go about finding different sheaf cohomology groups or for example the Hodge diamond, when what the space “is” is not explicit?(The example is the Klein cubic 3-fold.)

My initial guess is to see if it’s reducible, etc, and try to find an acyclic covering, from which I could use the Cech complex.

(For example for $x^2 + y^2 + z^2=0$ in $\mathbb{A}^3_{\mathbb{R}}$, we would use $X = S^2$.)

Comment: Usually you'd refer to results like Lefschetz' hyperplane theorem, Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch and some well known short exact sequences like the Euler sequence or the normal sequence. The adjunction formula comes to mind as well.

Comment: @user347489 Yes but it requires knowing what the space is. From the equation I have just given you, how would you find say, the canonical bundle on the manifold?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunction_formula#Adjunction_for_smooth_varieties